# Upload file Warning: move_uploaded_file(../view/pictureswhy.PNG): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php

Have been trying to upload an image and it is not working as expected. The error in the title is being displayed on the form. The image is being inserted via a file in the 'View' and checked in the 'Controller', however, when it comes to the final upload it fails, due to permissions I assume...

I have given both files in the view and controller the correct permissions for uploading files - in FileZilla.
[image]

The code is:
FORM - View

```
 <form class="article" id="article-form" name="article" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ol>
        <li>
            <label for="heading">Heading</label> <span id="headingMessage"></span>
            <input name="heading" id="heading" class="form-control" type="text" required>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="topic">Topic</label> <span id="topicMessage" required></span>
            <input name="topic" id="topic" class="form-control" type="text" list="football">
            <datalist id="football">
                <option value="Scotland"></option>
                <option value="England"></option>
                <option value="Spain"></option>
            </datalist>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="summary">Summary</label> <span id="summaryMessage"></span>
            <input name="summary" id="summary" class="form-control" type="text">
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="thumbnail">Thumbnail Link</label> <span id="thumbnailMessage"></span>
            <!-- <input name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" class="form-control" type="text" required> -->
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="video">Video</label> <span id="videoMessage"></span>
            <input name="video" id="video" class="form-control" type="text">
        </li>

        <li>
            <label for="articleText">Text</label> 
            <textarea name="articleText" id="articleText" class="md-textarea form-control" required></textarea>
        </li>

        <!-- <li>
         <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcUAnQUAAAAAPeF1u6Hcnf0Y5TfS4-0xitZ7ZeZ"></div>
        </li> -->

    </ol>
        <input class="btn btn-success" id="formButton" type="submit" name="submit"value="Submit" name="submit">
        <input class="btn btn-danger" id="formButton" type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

The controller -

```
//check image
$target_dir = "../view/pictures";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 0;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . "."; 
        $uploadOk = 2;
        //$thumbnail = '<img class="img-responsive" id="articleImage" src="'.$_POST["file"].'">';
        echo $target_file;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image. <hr>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

$thumbnail=$target_file;
include("../model/api-article.php") ;
if($uploadOk>1)
{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        $articleTxt = insertArticle($headline, $topic, $summary, $text, $thumbnail,$video,$date,$userId);
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}else{
    echo "Article not inserted - only upload images (PNG, JPEG)";
}

}
```

*Please excuse the indenting*

Comment: Don't use relative file pathing. Use the *absolute* filepath

Comment: The entire file path does not work, (Error - failed to open stream: No such file or directory ), is it the directory after public_html to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's may not enough to give permission to the upload file - you need to permit the whole folder where you are uploading your images.

Comment: Permisson remains closed - Error - failed to open stream: Permission denied in ....

Comment: yeah yeah you got it :)